# how to google search to return results in English

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to search Google for some products but the language of results Google is returning are dependent on the proxy, I have tried to fix it using `'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'` in my headers but still no use

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
products=["Majestic Pet Stairs Steps","Ball Jars Wide Mouth Lids 12/Pack","LED Duck Color Changing Floating Speaker"]
for product in products:
    headers = {
    'authority': 'www.google.com',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'}
    url = 'https://google.com/search?q={}'.format(product)
    PROXY = None 
    res=requests.get(url,headers=headers,proxies=PROXY)
    if res.status_code!=200:
        print("bad proxy")
        break
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    print(soup.title.text)
```

what I want is to get the results in English always (regardless of proxy)

Comment: `url = 'https://google.com/search?hl={}&q={}'.format('en', product)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to place [`uule=location`](https://valentin.app/uule.html), `hl=en` or `lr=lang_eng` parameters in the link of your request?

```py
response = request.get(`https://google.com/search?q=FUS RO DAH&hl=en`)
```

Or using URL [`params`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```py
params = {
   'q': 'FUS RO DAH',
   'hl': 'en', #  the language to use for the Google search
   'gl': 'us' # the country to use for the Google search
   'lr': 'lang_en' # one or multiple languages to limit the search to
   'uule': 'w+CAIQICIGQnJhemls' #Brazil # defines encoded location you want to use for the search
}
```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/
headers = {
   'user-agent': 
   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.134 Safari/537.36',
}

products = ["Majestic Pet Stairs Steps", "Ball Jars Wide Mouth Lids 12/Pack", "LED Duck Color Changing Floating Speaker"]

for product in products:
   params = {
   'q':  f'{product}',
   'hl': 'en',
   'gl': 'us' 
   'lr': 'lang_en'
   }
   html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
   print(soup)
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan of 100 searches to test out. Check out the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=spotlight%2029%20casino%20address&location=Brazil&google_domain=google.com.br&gl=br&hl=pt).

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "spotlight 29 casino address",
  "google_domain": "google.com.br",
  "gl": "br",
  "hl": "pt",
  "uule": "w+CAIQICIGQnJhemls",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

# print all titles from Google organic results
for result in results["organic_results"]:
    print(result["title"]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 1):

They provide an API for searching: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

If you do much automated querying via web scraping they are likely to start putting up a captcha or blocking you.

Comment: "Custom Search JSON API provides 100 search queries per day for free" that is too low for my task i

Answer (score 1):

There is this handy library I use for my searches, a snippet from my app :

pip install google for installation, [RFC](https://pypi.org/project/google/)

```
from googlesearch import search
results = list(search(str(tag)+' '+str(intitle), domains = ['stackoverflow.com'], stop = SITE.page_size))
```